# Django Admin LogEntry: how it works in non admin actions?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin, django-1.11

I am having some struggles how does exactly *django.admin.LogEntry* objects are created.

Consider the following scenario:

I have a bunch of functions which take a csv file with data that allow me to create multiple objects at one call (just iterate through the file, use the data and if data in given row is correct: create a Model instance). I want to make sure that that each of that creation will be logged.

The question is: django docs are not very descriptive on **how** does *LogEntry* works and I am not sure if such actions (not taken in the admin panel itself) will be logged there. Also: will the *LogEntries* be created for the related objects or I have to trigger them manually?

Does anybody got any experience with such scenarios and can share thoughts about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LogEntry model is in the Admin package and only used by Django admin by default. It is used in the admin layer and not model layer when saving objects. if you want to use it outside the admin, then you will have to manually create the entries yourself. That also means the admin will likely display entries of changes made by normal users so you have to think about how you want the entries displayed

Comment: I can pass the user_id as the function parameter so it's not a problem, I think. Then I will just put that ID in the .log_action function as there is a user_id keyword.
So if I understood you correctly: I have to create each log_actions myself, including the related object ones?

Comment: Yes, you have to create each yourself, including related objects if you wish to. Like I said, you have to consider if you wish the admin interface to display logs of changes made by non-admin users. It was originally meant to display changes made by the admin site users who are all admins

Comment: @Ken4scholars Django still does not log actions made by admin users to objects not created by the admin site. I would like to log that.

Comment: @hldev like I mentioned in my answer, you have to create the LogEntry objects yourself if it is not a case handled by Django Admin. You can just add it to the save method of the model you want to log